# CME historical data of futures prices

Tags: futures, historical-data, cme

Does CME provide any mechanism to freely download historical futures quotes for different futures traded there e.g. Henry hub NG?

I am looking for EoD data.

Comment: Every night CME provide a free file of all (!) EOD prices for that day, but it is completely unworkable if what you need is the price of 1 (or a few) commodities for an extended period of time (months and years). You can find free time series data in other places.

Comment: Is there any link/website to get the EOD quotes which you mentioned?

Comment: https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/energy/natural-gas/natural-gas.settlements.html